# Heroku issue with the GitHub token with Github deployment method

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

Why am I getting this error message for my apps deployed with Github at Heroku?

> There is an issue with the GitHub token for this app. Disconnect and reconnect to restore functionality

[image: issue with the Github token]

Comment: I am getting the same problem. I am trying to deploy connect my node.js app to Github without any luck.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well

Answer (score -2):

We had the same issue before, it happened with private repositories and disconnecting/reconnecting from time to time seems to do the trick but after a while we started to grow and we needed more automation.

We looked into all kinds of CI/CD tools like Codeship, CircleCi, etc. Ended up choosing DeployBot and stuck with it because it works really well for us and fitted our needs best.

Either way these tools can be lifesavers for the team no matter which one you end up using